# Starting 2D Game Project in Win32 API?

Tags: c++, winapi

I've recently started taking a look at C++ Win32 API for making a 2D game as my final project for my graduation this year. I've taken one full-year course in C++ console programming so I have good knowledge about the language.

I've spent the last 3 days around 6-8 hours every day on Google and libraries trying to find anything to get me started with this with no result whatsoever. I've taken a look at some code for basic windows which to me looks like an alien language.

Do anyone here know where a good starting point would be?

Help is really appreciated since my entire education, all 2300 hours in school, will be wasted if I don't succeed with this. Right now it just feels hopeless. We won't start with WinAPI until mid-November in our 2nd programming course and I can't waste 2 months sitting around doing nothing. The project's deadline is in mid-January...

Please don't refer me to DirectX, SDL, SDML, OpenGL, Allergo or any other graphic library.

My teacher told me about using images and that you can make some kind of areas of the window for collision etc. Is this achieveable?

Comment: Why don't you want to use a graphic library to do graphics?

Comment: Because if I do I can't develop on the schools' computers.

Comment: It is possible but not the best idea, you are using an non optimized approach. In my opinion its just "waste of time" you will learn a lot but there are best engines, libraries and you can do much more with them.

Comment: @Tobias Sundell you can put SDL on a pendrive or some kind of storage, you don't have to install it.

Comment: If you're looking to create a non-trivial game in 4 man-months alongside school, you can't realistically hope to do that without all sorts of helper libraries (graphics, user input, audio?, file parsing).

Comment: you can go with GDI/GDI+ but almost all library are usable without school computer modification.

Comment: @Angew It only needs to function and have a purpose; giving the game a goal so that the player can complete it. It'll be a very small game.

Comment: Go to amazon and buy a copy of this classic book http://www.charlespetzold.com/pw5/. It will teach basic graphics programming as well as all the other things you'll need to know about Win32 programming.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to use a plain Microsoft API, you have a few options that you will find [on the msdn page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee663279%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

If your version of windows is recent enough, the best is to use [Direct2D](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd370990%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). It's modern and the documentation is excellent.

[Direct3D](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh309466%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) has also been used for 2D graphics before Direct2D was available.

The old way is to use [GDI+](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms533798%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).